# Transition and opacity does not work well together

Tags: d3.js, transition, opacity

I set a 1500 ms duration for a transition triggered on click

On first run, the transition appears to be of 0 ms duration, which is not expected -_-

Mminimal example with corresponding fiddle (http://jsbin.com/pasodopeyati/3/edit) :

```
// create svg element
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr('width', 200).attr('height', 200);

// add 4 red circles
svg.selectAll('circle').data([{'n': 0}, {'n': 1}, {'n': 2}, {'n': 3}])
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr({
    cx: function(d, i) { return (i % 2) * 50 + 50;},
    cy: function(d, i) { return Math.floor(i / 2) * 50 + 50;},
    r:10,
    fill: 'red'
  });


// counter
var i = 0;  

// create button and bind on click
d3.select("body").append('button').text('fade').on('click', function () {
  // fade 3 circles alternatively (cf. counter)
  svg.selectAll('circle')
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .attr('opacity', function(d) { return d.n == i ? 1 : 0.1});

  i = (i + 1) % 4;
});
```

Try it! you'll notice that the first click will instantely fade 3 circles, and from that click on it will transition with a 1500ms duration as expected.

**How can I make the duration of the first transtion 1500 ms?**

Bonus: **Why is my code behaving as such?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the circles you haven't specified any opacity, so there's no from/to for the transition. Try this:

```
  .attr({
    cx: function(d, i) { return (i % 2) * 50 + 50;},
    cy: function(d, i) { return Math.floor(i / 2) * 50 + 50;},
    // need this starting value
    opacity: 1
    r:10,
    fill: 'red'
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think that the `opacity` is a `style` parameter and not an svg `attribute`. So you could as well have changed your line:

`.attr('opacity', function(d) { return d.n == i ? 1 : 0.1})`

to

`.style('opacity', function(d) { return d.n == i ? 1 : 0.1})`

having the same result.